# Nullpointerexception alertdialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I am trying to disable a button in alertdialog based on value entered in Edittext by user. I simply have to check the value and user, setEnabled(false) of the required button but things are not working properly. I am getting nullpointerexception error. I know that this happens when we use something which is null as it is non-null but I can't figure out where error is.Bellow is my code.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Title");
        alert.setMessage("Message");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);


        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString();
                // Do something with value!
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        if("".equals(input.getText().toString()) || input.getText().toString()==null){
            button.setEnabled(false);

        }
        else{
            int hour=Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(hour<=0 || hour>24){
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        dialog.show();
```

Logcat Trace:

```
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.example.blocka.Add_tabs.onClick(Add_tabs.java:97)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-15 13:13:18.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 13:13:21.278: E/InputDispatcher(71): channel '40f398c8 com.example.blocka/com.example.blocka.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
03-15 13:13:21.288: E/InputDispatcher(71): channel '40f398c8 com.example.blocka/com.example.blocka.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-15 13:13:21.528: E/InputDispatcher(71): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=188, events=0x8
```

Comment: in what line is the NPE? logcat output?

Comment: I have edited the question with logcat trace.

Comment: we know it is line 97 but could you please mark in your code where is this line ?

Comment: Sorry, Line 97 corresponds to button.setEnabled(false); The first instance of it.

Comment: `button` is probably null because the Objects in the AlertDialog aren't instantiated until `show()` is called. Apart from that, I believe your logic is faulty. If, indeed, you do get a reference to that button, it will always be disabled, as you are not accounting for changes in the EditText's text.

Comment: @Mike M , I have consideration of it. My first step is to disable the button and then I will go further. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Mike M, Thanks for your comment. It is working I just had to put alert.show() before doing any disable thingy. I thought create() instantiates the alertdialog without showing it to the user.